# Rails 3 devise user registration edit path not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have a pretty straight forward app with a couple tweaks to Devise.

First I created a Registrations controller that `class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController` inherits from Devise.  I created this controller so that I could edit users without re-supplying passwords. https://gist.github.com/1514687

I also did this in my routes:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations" }`
```

The signup works fine but when I call the following:

```
<p class="edit"><%= link_to "Edit", edit_user_registration_path(user) %></p>
```

The url it spits out is (running on localhost): `http://localhost:3000/users/edit.2`

Any ideas here?

Comment: Does this url work? If so - what's the problem? If not - can you let us know what the error generated says?

Comment: Rake routes: https://gist.github.com/1515053  The view renders but no matter which user (there are 4) it renders the edit action for user id=1

Comment: Ok I figured out what I think is happening.  I am looping through users which is why its trying to get user id=1 no matter which user I click on.  any ideas how to loop through users but still provide a edit_path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend a non-devise controller for doing this, and name it something other that "users" for the sake of not overlapping with devise routes

some key nomenclature:

```
rails g controller accounts
resources :accounts

def edit
 @user = User.find(params[:id]
end
```

(other controller actions similar, just refer to @user and don't worry about that this happens to be called the accounts controller)

Comment: I think I follow but then what kind of path am I sending through: edit_accounts_path(user)?

Answer (score 1):

In your routes.rb file make sure that you have

```
resources :users
```

after your devise_for line like below:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations" }
resources :users
```