# Admin Change Approval Status of User - Rails + Devise + Cancancan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, cancan

I followed this [link](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Require-admin-to-activate-account-before-sign_in) to figure out how to have an admin approve a new user.  I have an `approved` attribute on my `User` model that is a boolean.

2 problems - 1) when I'm logged in as admin and go to the edit user via the `link_to "Edit", edit_user_path(user)` to change approved user - the url is for the correct user but then the update action tries to update the current admin user.

2) I would prefer to have the override of the needed current password so I've put a method in the `Registrations` controller to do this below but get this error:

error:`unknown attribute 'current_password' for User.`

So it won't override the `current_password` and it won't update the correct non-admin user - 
Where am I going wrong?

```
class Ability
      include CanCan::Ability

      def initialize(user)

       current_user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
        if current_user.admin == true
          can :manage, :all
        else
          can :manage, User, id: user.id
        end       
      end
    end
```

Routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: 'registrations' }
  resources :users
end
```

Controller

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def update_resource(resource, params)
    resource.update_without_password(params) if current_user.admin == true
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent a lot of time trying to solve this and didn't find any definitive, end-to-end complete examples online so I'm putting everything below so any new users to RoR/Devise hopefully won't have same problems.

Assuming `Devise` is on the `User` model.
Ensure your Cancancan is setup accordingly.  Something similar to this:

models/ability.rb

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    # Define abilities for the passed in user here. For example:
    #
    current_user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
    if current_user.admin
      can :manage, :all
    else
      can :manage, User, id: user.id
    end
 end
end
```

Follow the steps in [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Require-admin-to-activate-account-before-sign_in)

He mentions have an 'admin-accessible only' page.  In case someone's not sure how to do this:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :admin?, only: :index

  def index
    if params[:approved] == false
      @users = User.where(approved: false)
    else
      @users = User.all
    end
  end

private
  def admin?
    redirect_to '/login' unless current_user.admin == true
  end

end
```

Replace this line (I use .erb not .haml as he does in the link) `%td= link_to "Edit", edit_user_path(user)` with this:
              <%= User.approved %>

```
          <td>
            <% if !User.approved %>
              <%= link_to "Approve User", user_path(:id => user.id, "user[approved]" => true), :method => :patch, class: "btn btn-success" %>
            <% else %>
              <%= link_to "Unapprove User", user_path(:id => user.id, "user[approved]" => false), :method => :patch, class: "btn btn-danger" %>
            <% end %>
          </td>
```

This essentially gives you a button that when clicked, will approve the user and visa-versa.  The key here that tripped me up for days is that a) You have to ensure that your form (in this case, the `link_to` hits the Users controller and NOT the `RegistrationsController#update` method.

I know some online links gave instructions to create a `Registrations` model and changing routes, overriding models, etc.

Honestly, my final solution didn't need any of that. Hope this helps!